# Pressing a button which acts like a keyboard? Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have 10 buttons, each with a letter. I want it so once 1 button has been pressed, it's shown in a text view. So I can press the 10 buttons and have all the 'letters' type in the uitextview?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused on how I would make the uitextview linked to the IBAction button, could you help me please.

Comment: You do not directly link the button-action towards the textView. You implement a button-action that takes the current content of the textView, adds the new letter and writes it back to that textView.

Comment: Would I define the textView as an IBOutlet, link it via the nib, then implement it to the button? I'm not sure how to do it, what is the code needed. Thanks for your help. I'm a beginner by the way as you probably can tell.

Comment: Read some tutorials and try yourself. You will not learn anything if I simply write the code for you. Enjoy the rewarding feeling of getting it done yourself!

Comment: Okay, could you point me to some tutorials? What would I type into google to find this? Thanks for the help Till!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15089/discussion-between-plies-neyo-and-till)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your buttons in a custom view container, and change the input view property of the text view. When the text view becomes active, your view will show up instead of the keyboard (if this is what you are trying to accomplish).

If you don't want to do this, and rather have the buttons visible at all time, you can just disable user iteration with the textview, capture the actions of the button, have an outlet/ivar with your textview, and append the new text content base on the click of the button.